# How to get last record from column if there is no any unique ID for this record?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example there are two columns, "timestamp" and "value".

```
time_stamp             value

2014-12-11 08:00       12424     
2014-12-11 08:00       42
2014-12-11 08:00       9444444
2014-12-11 08:00       2323
2014-12-11 08:00       447
```

How do I get 447?

I tried  SELECT LAST(value) FROM table_name;
but think I'ts actually only for MS Access. Any idea?

I was looking for an answer in almost the same questions here but still can't figure this out. Thanks

Comment: `select * from table_name order by time_stamp desc limit 1`

Comment: well, write it as an answer so it can get accepted, others can find it usefull. the ones that don't know how to google anyways :)

Comment: Not trying to claim victory here by answering it, just want an accepted answer for people who come here from the outside, if anyone else posts the same answer I'ma remove mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table_name order by time_stamp desc limit 1
```

Comment: Sorry? How this guaranties that it returns 447? Maybe a question for OP: Regarding timestamp, is there something we cannot see?If those are the same, the result 447 is not guarantied...